# jquery ajax data was send but no success event is triggered

Tags: jquery

I have a database on my webdomain which i am accessing from my local mashine through jquery ajax.

here is the code that i use.

```
    var domain = 'http://subdomain.mydomain.com/';
    var path = 'funcx.php?insert=true&listname=notes&listdata=author.'+author+',subject.'+subject+',thenote.'+thenote+'';
    var URI = domain+path;

    $.ajax({
      url: URI,
      type : "get",
      success: function(data){
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
```

**Backend:**

I have in my backend some PHP that can parse the data being send.  It works 100%.  The data is parsed, and put into a database.  So the JS Ajax do send the data to the server, but i get an "error" popup message everytime.

I dont understand why this is happening, since i have a succes sending the data.

Any ideas?

**The solution was**

I put this into my main php file that has the control over it all.

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: try [Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check out what headers you get back from the request - perhaps you're getting headers that tells the browser something's wrong regardless of the response text you might be seeing

Comment: change the error handler to `error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
          alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
      }`

Comment: Probably, something is going wrong on the server after the database is updated. That would return a 500 error that would in turn trigger the `error` code in your jQuery script. Look at the server logs.

Comment: please show a copy of the response from the PHP script, including headers

Comment: I got this response from Chrome inspector:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://submdoain.mydomain.com/funcx.php?insert=true&listname=notes&listdata=author.asdasd,subject.asd,thenote.asda. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: it would have been very useful to have included that information in the original question!

Comment: @Alnitak the php script do not response with anything when the data is send.  I tested this on my local mashine without going online, and sucess pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a resource that is not in the same domain as the page from which the script was downloaded, resulting in a "Cross Origin" security error.

You have two options:

1. change your page and PHP script to support "JSONP", or
2. change your PHP script to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  i just put this into my php file.

Comment: I assume given the speed at which you changed it that you used the latter option.  If this is for a live service (i.e. on the internet) do yourself a favour and read up on "CORS" and satisfy yourself that there are no security implications in allowing sites from other (third party) domains being allowed to access that PHP script's data.

Comment: yea, atm its just for testing.  However thanks for helping.  :)